# how to create an application that creates the resource files dynamically reading from an excel sheet using c#?

Tags: c#

My requirement is  create an application that creates the resource files dynamically reading from an excel sheet .

In that i have done with reading values from excel. and I know how to create resource file dynamically .But I am not getting any idea how to create resource file dynamically by reading values from excel sheet .

In my project localization concept is there. We need to create multiple resource files from the excel sheet.

Comment: So what exactly you are stuck with - you can read Excel file, you can create resource file... that seem to be all you need for your own requirements...

Comment: I am able to read excel file and i know how to create resource file dynamically,but how to create dynamically resource file by using the excel sheet ?

Comment: Dynamically at runtime or before compile time?

Comment: After running our application I need to see the resource files with data(from excel data)